# Teams JS - File Attachment Message in Task Module

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams, microsoft-teams-js

I would like to display the title of this file attachment in an embedded web view Task Module that is launched from this command.  Is it possible to obtain this data using the Teams JS library?

[Compose Extension command in message context](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tkUu2.png)

Comment: There does not seem to be possible scenario with the Teams JS library.